# Getting $scope.variable in ng-if

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to simply use $scope.variable name like this

```
<a href="index.html" ng-if="{{variableName}}"> <!-- angular.js:11706 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key -->
```

How do I use {{variableName}} inside the ng-if statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace with this

```
 <a href="index.html" ng-if="variableName">
```

Answer (score 0):

use the category with in square bracket[].

```js
angular.module('app',[])
.controller('ctrl',function($scope){
    $scope.categoryList = [
        {Name : '1'},
        {Name : '2'},
        {Name : '3'},
        {Name : '4'},
        {Name : '5'}
    ];
    
    $scope.gameList = [
        {Name : 'g1', '1':true},
         {Name : 'g2', '1':true},
         {Name : 'g3', '2':true},
         {Name : 'g4', '7':true}
    ]
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="category in categoryList">
      Category - {{category.Name}} <br>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="game in gameList" ng-if="game[category.Name]">
          Game - {{game.Name}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```